# Kingmaker Kobold treasure question (Spoilers)

Tags: pathfinder-1e, treasure, adventure-path

Spoilers for Kingmaker.

> In Kingmaker, the PCs have the option to join forces with the kobolds, if they rescue the statue for them.  There is also quite a list of treasure, that I imagine is supposed to be part of their wealth-by-level.  There's nothing in the book about them getting the treasure if they become allies with the kobolds.

Are they supposed to get the treasure at all?

> Should I have the kobolds award it to them for returning the treasure?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### That's up to you, but there is a reward already

[Kingmaker](http://paizo.com/store/pathfinder/adventures/adventurePath/kingmaker) is a very [sandboxy](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/662/what-is-sandbox-play) campaign, and if you actually sum up all the treasure, the party will likely be over their [Wealth by Level](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/character-advancement). Especially if you add some random encounters during their exploration. The reward quest for that is explained on page 34:

> **Reward**: Delivering the statue to Tartuk wins the PCs safe passage out of the kobold lair as well as a shiny 500 gp topaz and (if the PCs ask for it) Svetlana’s wedding ring from the shaman. Delivering the statue to Chief Sootscale wins them instead the ring, the shaman’s gear, the eternal thanks of the kobold chieftain and, perhaps, an actual alliance with the Sootscale tribe.

Keep in mind that the quest given by the swordlords (which is a different quest) is to keep the kobolds activity *under control*, and resolving their conflict surely is a way of controlling it. That reward should be given regardless of the outcome. But of course, they will likely get a higher treasure total if they get the reward and *also* murder all the kobolds.

However, if you believe they are under WBL, you may also fix that by adding a few more exploration encounters that will reward them with treasures. But, by no means, the kobolds *have* to give the party their valuables.

In my group, the kobolds were hired to be scouts and miners in our kingdom, which translated as a free mine once we absorbed their hex and a tiny army of scouts that never actually got used, but were there defending the mine hex, which was far more valuable in the long run to us.

Answer (score 2):

I totally agree with ShadowKras. It is entirely up to you but it seems the AP is geared a little towards befriending them. My players also befriended them and got a free mine as well.

All-in-all, I found the wealth of Kingmaker to be low, so you may want to have the kobolds offer more. Maybe have the PCs make Charisma checks to see how much the kobolds like them.